# What are the indicators of a country being in a financial crisis

Tags: financial-crises

What are the indicators of a country being in a financial crisis?

I would like to know both about the acute and recovery phase.

I am trying to make a point to our company that we are not growing despite the financial crisis being over.

Comment: Usually the first thing to look at are index: Dow Jones, NASDAQ for instance. For example, between 2007 and 2009, the Nasdaq composite lost 50% of its value: http://www.abcbourse.com/graphes/eod.aspx?s=@CCOu

Comment: Also, in case of a structured financial crisis. You will see real economy to be affected at a later stage. Initially, the numbers in the shadow banking system, the banking system etc will start to affect. That is why it becomes difficult to track financial crises.

Comment: Please write the question more clearly. It looks like what you wanted to ask is: "What are the indicators of a country being in a financial crisis?". Also, the crisis can be thought of as having an acute period and then a recovery or aftermath that might be quite long. So you might want to state that you care about whether we are still in the recovery phase, or we are all done with the crisis.